# Not able to load images from a Bundle included inside a Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, resources, bundle

I have created an iOS **Framework** (lets call the content of it app-1) that includes other than the source code, a Storyboard, and some **Bundles** that includes some images in them.
and I am using this **Framework** in another project(lets call it app-2), and starting the Storyboard from app-2.
it works fine for the most part, but my problem is with the images that are loaded using

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"OneOfTheBundles.bundle/someImage.png"];
```

Now when running app-1, everything seem to be okay, and images display correctly.
but when running the **Framework** inside app-2, the static images are fine, but the ones that are loaded using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` are not showing up.

a small solution i found was to add the **Bundles** that contains the images to the app-2 files, then the images starts showing up.

But is there a way to do it without the need of delivering all the **Bundles** alongside the **Framework**. I mean why isn't the **Framework** looking at the **Bundles** included inside it ?

Can someone please let me know what am I missing ?!
this problem has been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] compatibleWithTraitCollection:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]];
```

instead of

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE"];
```

Comment: I think self class and your framework class will give same answer because when we set nil bundle that time it finds that resource in main bundle but here you wrote self class so in which class you wrote that line its find in that class bundle means your framework bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourFramework class]];
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"cross.jpg" ofType:nil];
```

Set bundle path as your framework path

I hope it will help you!

Comment: That didn't work with me :(

is there maybe a way to add the Framework to the Search Locations ?

Comment: Check updated answer. Fetach resources from your framework bundle

Comment: thank you for the help, i did find the answer somewhere else. Please check my answer below